# Is it possible to Tail call optimize (TCO) a recursive class generator?

Tags: javascript, recursion, iterator, generator

Is it possible to create a Tail Call Optimized (TCO) recursive generator Class? I appreciate that this can be accomplished with functions, reduce, etc. and that in essence requires a function return in a tail position or helpers like `trampoline`, but is it possible to do so with generator / iterator Class?

The best approach I can make work is a stack TCO which seems like overkill so I'm looking for a more experienced opinion on the best approach.

I appreciate TCO is more typically associated with recursive function calls rather than object-oriented or iterator-based structures, but I've been trying to find an answer to this question and have yet to find an answer. The ECMAScript spec doesn't clearly state if it does or doesn't.

- **First attempt** (recursive yield delegation):

  My original starting point was a recursive generator class that creates a new `RecursiveGenerator` instance and delegates to it with `yield*` if it has `children` (children property with hydrated array). According the ECMAScript spec I it seems that delegation via yield* mechanism handles recursion in a memory-efficient way as yield* is not consuming extra memory with additional stack frames like with a traditional recursive function call, but again no specifics.

  ```js
  class RecursiveIterator {
      constructor(iterable) {
          this._iterable = iterable
      }

      hasChildren(node) {
          return !!node && Object.hasOwn(node, 'children') && Array.isArray(node.children)
      }

      * [Symbol.iterator]() {
          for (const node of this._iterable.values()) {
          if (this.hasChildren(node)) {
              yield* new RecursiveIterator(node.children)
          }

          yield node
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Second attempt** (expression-ish):

  Attempted a `yield*` delegation method inside of the constructor in an attempt to delegate to another generator or iterable object. While yield* does provide a mechanism to handle recursion in a way that is more memory-efficient than a traditional recursive function call, it doesn't seem to be TCO.

  ```js
    class RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2 {
      constructor(iterable) {
        this._iterable = iterable
      }

      * generator(iterable = this._iterable) {
        for (const node of iterable) {
          if (node.children) {
            yield* this.generator(node.children)
          }

          yield node
        }
      }

      * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this.generator()
      }
    }
  ```
- **Third attempt** (stack iteration):

  Stack approach loosely based on stack approach. Using the `_stack` property is used to keep track of nested iteration structure. This approach data is handled iteratively rather than recursively, but gets me closest.

  ```js
   class RecursiveGeneratorAttemptStack {
      constructor(iterable) {
        this._iterable = iterable;
        this._stack = [];
        this._index = 0;

        return {
          [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
            return {
              next: () => {
                while (this._iterable[this._index] || this._stack.length > 0) {
                  if (this._iterable[this._index]) {
                    const value = this._iterable[this._index];
                    this._index += 1;
                    if (value.children) {
                      this._stack.push([this._iterable, this._index]);
                      this._iterable = value.children;
                      this._index = 0;
                    }
                    return { value, done: false };
                  } else {
                    [this._iterable, this._index] = this._stack.pop();
                  }
                }
                return { done: true };
              },
            };
          },
        };
      }
    }
  ```
- **Fourth attempt based on feedback** (cont. expression-ish):

Replaced `* [Symbol.iterator]() { yield* this._iterator}` with `* [Symbol.iterator]() { return yield* this._iterator}`

```js
 class RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2 {
  //...removed it for brevity's sake as it is the same as RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2 except for [Symbol.iterator]
  * [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return yield* this._iterator
  }
}
```

** Four snippets (Fourth based on comments):**

```js
class RecursiveIteratorAttempt1 {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this._iterable = iterable
  }

  hasChildren(node) {
    return !!node && Object.hasOwn(node, 'children') && Array.isArray(node.children)
  }

  * [Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const node of this._iterable.values()) {
      if (this.hasChildren(node)) {
        yield* new RecursiveIteratorAttempt1(node.children)
      }

      yield node
    }
  }
}

class RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2Expr {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this._iterable = iterable
  }

  * generator(iterable = this._iterable) {
    for (const node of iterable) {
      if (node.children) {
        yield* this.generator(node.children)
      }

      yield node
    }
  }

  * [Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* this.generator()
  }
}

class RecursiveGeneratorAttempt3Stack {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this._iterable = iterable;
    this._stack = [];
    this._index = 0;

    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
        return {
          next: () => {
            while (this._iterable[this._index] || this._stack.length > 0) {
              if (this._iterable[this._index]) {
                const value = this._iterable[this._index];
                this._index += 1;
                if (value.children) {
                  this._stack.push([this._iterable, this._index]);
                  this._iterable = value.children;
                  this._index = 0;
                }
                return { value, done: false };
              } else {
                [this._iterable, this._index] = this._stack.pop();
              }
            }
            return { done: true };
          },
        };
      },
    };
  }
}

class RecursiveGeneratorAttemptBergi {
  constructor(iterable) {
    this._iterable = iterable;
  }
  
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    return yield* this.generator();
  }
  
  *generator(iterable = this._iterable) {
    for (const node of iterable) {
      if (node.children) {
        yield* this.generator(node.children);
      }

      yield node;
    }
  }
}

const iterable = [
  {
    name: 'New York',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'London',
      },
      {
        name: 'Paris',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Berlin',
          },
          {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Sydney',
              },
              {
                name: 'Moscow',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Beijing',
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Cairo',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'San Francisco',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'San Jose',
      },
      {
        name: 'Oakland',
      },
      {
        name: 'Fresno',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Sacramento',
          },
          {
            name: 'Long Beach',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const _attemptDelegating1 = new RecursiveIteratorAttempt1(iterable)
const _attemptExpr2 = new RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2Expr(iterable)
const _attemptStack3 = new RecursiveGeneratorAttempt3Stack(iterable)
const _attemptBergi = new RecursiveGeneratorAttemptBergi(iterable)

for (const node of _attemptDelegating1) {
  console.log('RecursiveIteratorAttempt1 node : ', node)
}

for (const node of _attemptExpr2) {
  console.log('RecursiveGeneratorAttempt2Expr node : ', node)
}

for (const node of _attemptStack3) {
  console.log('RecursiveGeneratorAttempt3Stack node : ', node)
}

for (const node of _attemptBergi) {
  console.log('RecursiveGeneratorAttemptBergi node : ', node)
}
```

Sources:

- [Axel Rauschmayer](https://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html#tail-recursive-functions)
- [Understanding ECMAScript 6](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read)

Comment: You might be able to produce a tail call recursive version, which in turn is possible to be tail call optimised. With that said, to my knowledge no JS engine implements TCO. So, if you want the optimisation you might need to create that as well, e.g., via a trampoline.

Comment: Isn't the use of a stack in contradiction with the aim of TCO? In general, TCO is only possible if you only have *one* recursive call, and it is the last thing you do. Neither is true here, because you have a loop with recursive calls, and the last thing is still not a recursive call, but a yield of the current node.

Comment: "*it seems that delegation via `yield*` mechanism handles recursion in a memory-efficient way as `yield*` is not consuming extra memory with additional stack frames*" - uh, no? Where did you get that from?

Comment: "*gets me closest*" - to what exactly? Please post how you are using these classes and calling their methods (although really it doesn't seem relevant that they're `class`es, you could achieve the same with normal generator functions), and elaborate on which calls exactly you would expect to be tail-call-optimised. As far as I can see, `Array.isArray` is the only tail call in your code.

Comment: `*[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* this.generator() }` cannot be tail-call-optimised, it still has to produce `undefined` in the end. `*[Symbol.iterator]() { return yield* this.generator() }` *could* be optimised, but won't be even by the ES6 spec. Realistically, you can however do `[Symbol.iterator]() { return this.generator() }` which gets rid of the intermediate generator function altogether

Comment: @Bergi thank you for taking the time to answer. To answer the question "gets me closest". I'm using `RecursiveGenerator` to iterate Vue nested routes, which I inject into a `class RouteEnumerator {}`. That way, I can abstract `route recursion` from `route enumeration`. I normalize the route data in recursion and then enumerate to set meta, state, permissions, etc.

Comment: @Bergi Based on your answer I adjusted to `*[Symbol.iterator]() { return yield* this.generator()}` as `*[Symbol.iterator]() { return this.generator()}` doesn't return an iterable. I've included the snippet as the forth snippet below.

Comment: @Nolan It's `[Symbol.iterator]() { return … }` not `*[Symbol.iterator]() { return … }`. But really this was not to suggest a new variant, rather to show that there's not much difference between your first and second attempt.

Comment: And no, I still don't get the question. Where do you expect a tail call optimisation to take place?

Comment: @Bergi my question/assumption is that recursive traversal using `yield*` delegation, as per the example, cannot be TCO as returning  `yield*` delegation ends iteration [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) and therefore not an option, i.e., replacing `yield* this.generator(node.children)` with `return yield* this.generator(node.children)` is not an option as such recursive `yield*` delegation will grow the stack and therefore not an option for deeply nested iterables that require TCO.

Comment: Yes, there is no TCO. But it's still not clear what you mean by "*iterables that require TCO*" - it is impossible to tail-call-optimise anything about `this.generator(node.children)`, it's inside a loop, before other code, not in a tail position.